# Which of the following two (apparently)possible meanings is the right one?

Tags: double-negation

Here's a conversation I had:
A:"don't strain your brain"
B:"can't happen when I'm talking to you"
Does this imply that it's impossible for A to strain their brain while talking to B, or,
Is it that it's impossible for B to NOT strain it while talking to A?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is rather confusing. Could you edit it for clarity? Maybe provide some context--was this a conversation you heard or a dialogue you read? A common convention to show dialogue/conversation is to use an ABAB format...
A: Don't strain your brain!
B: Can't happen when I'm talking to you
A: Are you calling me stupid?
B: I would never say that! Out loud, anyway...

Comment: It could be either. The joke works the same: A is saying B ain’t bright. In the former interpretation, as a more blunt statement of fact; in the latter, so dumb it hurts. Doesn’t matter either way, the message has been sent.

Comment: Absent more context, I would say it implies that A is stupid. But no doubt someone will come up with a brain-surgery scenario where the meaning could be different.

Comment: B is implying that nothing A could possibly say would require a level of brain activity anywhere near the point where it might get strained.  In other words “A, you’re too dumb to say anything thought provoking.”

Comment: @Jim This is the correct assessment. I'm not sure why this question became closed. This is factual based on the information OP provided.

Comment: @Jim Finally, thank you Jim. Could you please explain why it couldn't be the other meaning?

Answer (score 1):

A is offering an amusing insult to B. B is offering a come-back related to the claim.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers. Opinions or anecdotes can occasionally be useful, but they are usually not sufficient to show that an answer is right. An answer should include explanation, context, and supporting facts. For example, you could offer peer-reviewed evidence, such as the definition from a good online dictionary. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @MetaEd I don't believe this answer is incorrect per se but it requires some additional exposition to show how it answer's OP's question.

Comment: @psosuna I agree. At this point, it's neither right nor wrong, because it's an idea or opinion. It could be turned into an answer.

Comment: It actually has absolutely nothing to do with my question, since I asked whether it implies that it's impossible for B to strain their brain or if it's impossible for B to not strain it. I never asked for a narration of the situation.